# How to directly read a 4-byte data into a 8-byte variable in fortran?

Tags: io, binary, fortran, byte

Suppose there is a 4-byte int data stored in a binary data file e.g. data.bin

But I want to read it directly to a 8-byte variable?

There is a test code:

```
INTEGER*4 :: I,J,K
INTEGER*8 :: L

   OPEN(6,FILE='data.bin',,FORM='UNFORMATTED',ACCESS='STREAM',ACTION='READWRITE',STATUS='REPLACE')

       I=1; J=2; K=3;
       WRITE(6) I,J,K

       REWIND(6)

       READ(6) L
       READ(6) I

       WRITE(*,*) L, I

   CLOSE(6)
```

It turns out tha I=3, but L is neither 1 nor 2

How could I read the first int data (I=1) into L?

Comment: You cannot do a short read in Fortran.  `READ(6) L` will read `STORAGE_SIZE(L)` number of bits, which is twice as many bits as `STORAGE_SIZE(I)`, or an IO error will occur.

Comment: So the number of bits to be read (4-byte) is smaller than that for storage (8-byte L).  I believe there must be an easy way to directly ahieve that without using an intermediate buffer....

Comment: Use an intermediate buffer, it is much the easiest way (and may be the only one, I can't think of another) - Fortran is a high level language, you should avoid thinking in bits wherever possible. Also learn about Fortran kinds - integer*4 and integer*8 are not and have never been part of Fortran.

Comment: Also don't use units < 10 in your code. In this case unit 6 is very dangerous as normally this is attached to the standard output.

Comment: You can read the 32-bit integer into a `INTEGER` and then use `TRANSFER` to store those bits into a 64-bit integer.  I'm not sure if you can do much with that 64-bit integer as it is not not actually defined

Comment: The problem is that I need to read a large array of  data. They can be either Single-Precision or Double-Precision. But I just want use a Double-Precision array to store the different-bit data in an unified way. It's tested that using an intermediate buffer would significantly slow down reading the data. And I don't want to define two arrays, one to store the single-precision data the other to store the double-precision data. :(

Comment: Just use the dambed buffer. I do not believe it is the cause of the slow-down unless you show the code and test results.

Comment: I have to agree with Vladimir. Remember memory is MUCH quicker than disk, so a the time for memory copy or two will be dwarfed by the time to read the file, unless you are doing something very strange.

Comment: I get it .... Further tests showed that the slow-down is mainly caused by read/write the data one element by one element, rather than using buffer ... Orz